# (excel) Calculated Field not available for a power pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerpivot

I'm trying to create a column in a pivot table I've created that calculates the difference between a forecast and actual cost column. Under 'Fields, Items, & Sets', 'calculated field' is grayed out/unavailable. From other forum posts as far back as 2010 (all with dead links to websites meant to explain it more), I've heard that this has something to do with using data that comes from an OLAP table.

My 'actual cost' data is being pulled from a server and funneled into a group of tables on separate sheets. I also have a manual entry sheet for the forecasts (also type table) that's being connected to it. that I'm  The cell count is in the millions and steadily increasing, so it's understandable that the system uses OLAP to refresh manually (it takes about a minute to 'refresh all'). That said, I don't know why this would prevent me from doing math with these columns. I've looked up some videos on OLAP and I figure it's just above my head. I've looked into converting it into a "dynamic range" per a recommendation from about 10 years ago, but there isn't much about what that actually is online and I'm not sure I'd be able to do that with how I'm pulling it from the database. That, and I'm doing about 2 weeks worth of operations that are probably dependent on it being a table. I'm not even sure if you can feed data into power pivot if it's not a table.

I have a way that I think I can do this, but it requires about a week's worth of work manually building out a massive, un-iterative sheet. It would pull all of the values for a specific job of each activity type, sum them, and then compile them into another table that can be used to find the difference between the values of forecast and actual. But, at that point I'm basically just making a worse pivot table infrastructure from scratch.

Is there a way that I can just side-step this issue? I've only been using power pivot for a few weeks and this is the first time I've had to do math between columns, so it may be that I'm missing something that most people know.

Comment: Not sure to understand you, but it seems what you are looking for is a “calculated column” within your powerPivot model: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculated-columns-in-power-pivot-a0eb7167-33fc-4ade-a23f-fb9217c193af (a pivot table as a feature to “transform” a range or table from a sheet is not the same as a table in your powerPivot model)

Comment: Depending how you pulled over your data from other sources, you could also add the calculated column within PowerQuery (aka “Get and Transform”): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-power-query-and-power-pivot-work-together-a5f52cba-2150-4fc0-bb8f-b21d69990bc0

Comment: You can still apply the pivot table feature to the tables from your powerPivot model as well.

Comment: Finally, there are also “calculated measures” in powerPivot which are similar to “calculated fields” in a pivot table: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/measures-in-power-pivot-86484821-a324-4da3-803b-82fd2e5033f4